# error from a server in java

Tags: java, multithreading

I have the follwing code which is a thread pool in java which accepts only one client

```
public class ServerThread implements Runnable {

    ServerSocket serverSocket;
    Socket clientSocket;
    protected boolean isStopped = false;
    int serverPort = 6500;
    private String serverIpAddress = "127.0.0.1";
    DataInputStream is;
    ObjectOutputStream os=null;

    protected BlockingQueue queue = null;


    protected ExecutorService threadPool2 =
    Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);

    public ServerThread(BlockingQueue queue) { 
        this.queue=queue;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            InetSocketAddress serverAddr = new InetSocketAddress(serverIpAddress, serverPort);
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket();
            serverSocket.bind(serverAddr);

            System.out.println("s-a creat");

        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            System.err.println("Don't know about host");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        while(!isStopped()){
            clientSocket=null;

            try{            
                clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
    }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();        
            }

            WorkerServerRunnable workerRunnable = new WorkerServerRunnable(queue,clientSocket);
            this.threadPool2.execute(workerRunnable);

        }
        this.threadPool2.shutdown();
        System.out.println("Server Stopped.");
    }

    private synchronized boolean isStopped(){
        return this.isStopped;
    }

    public synchronized void stop() {
        this.isStopped = true;
        try {
            this.serverSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error closing server", e);
        }

    }

}
```

But the problem is that I cannot get my server in ON state.
I mean once I press run I get the following error:

> java.net.SocketException: Socket is not bound yet
>       at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(Unknown Source)
>       at servers.ServerThread.run(ServerThread.java:60)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>   java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
>       at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
>       at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
>       at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(Unknown Source)
>       at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(Unknown Source)
>       at servers.ServerThread.run(ServerThread.java:44)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Even if I shutdown my whole app and run it again still the same error....has anyone any idea why?Thank u!

Comment: This is really painful to read unindented code. Please format it.

Comment: Did you try a different port?

Comment: @Talha you can (and should!) edit the question.

Comment: I believe my code is correct formatted!

Comment: For small code I do love to indent, but its really a big code. Anyway I guess the question has been answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some other program is already using port 6500.  Check that you're not running another instance of your program.

Try running

```
netstat -lp
```

to see what processes are using which ports.  Make sure the port on which you wish to listen is not listed in the output from `netstat`.

Answer (score 2):

In the run() method, when you are creating a ServerSocket and assigning it to serverSocket variable:

> serverSocket = new ServerSocket();

Please give a port number in the ServerSocket constructor, like 5000

> serverSocket = new ServerSocket(5000);